# C# winforms 4.0 datagridview multiselect checkboxes

Tags: datagridview, multi-select, datagridviewcheckboxcell

Multiselection DataGridView and checkbox column inside it. I would like to allow a user check/uncheck all selected rows at time, but when one checkbox is checked  selection moves to this row (and other rows becomes unselected).

Q: Is any way to prevent selection change in DatagridView when user check/uncheck checkbox ?

Comment: [Related link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405849/c-sharp-datagridview-checkbox-independant-from-row-selection)